# How to execute Javascript in selenium with function who haven`t any params?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to use function who haven`t any params :

```
function usunK(){
    var poziomWarstwy = currentRozdzial==""?0:currentRozdzial;
    var tabela = tabelaManager.znajdzElementyPoziomuRozdzialu()[currentTable];
    var tabela_EIS = document.getElementById("TABELA_EIS" + currentRozdzial + "_" + currentTable);
    var rows = parseInt(liczbaWierszy.get(poziomWarstwy)[currentTable]);
    var cols = parseInt(liczbaKolumn.get(poziomWarstwy)[currentTable]);     
    var rowsNaglCount = tabelaManager.getLiczbaWierszyNagl(tabela.rowsNagl);
    var komorka_EIS = selection.getSelectedCell_EIS();

    var col = komorka_EIS.col.nr;
```

my solution is :

```
if(driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
((JavascriptExecutor) driver) 
        .executeScript("setOnClickKomorka({col: 1, colspan: 1, row: 1,rowspan: 1, siatkaCol: 1,siatkaRow: 1})");}
if(driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
((JavascriptExecutor) driver) 
        .executeScript("usunK({getSelectedCell_EIS:{col: 1, colspan: 1, row: 1,rowspan: 1, siatkaCol: 1,siatkaRow: 1}})");}
}}}
```

setOnClickKomorka location (col: 1, colspan: 1, row: 1,rowspan: 1, siatkaCol: 1,siatkaRow: 1) position and later I want use function usunK(this function delete col in my table) but I don't know how, because there haven`t any parameters.

If I run my selenium script  I have error "komorka_EIS is undefined".
Element have only dynamic id and i can`t use findElement by xpath